# file_exists and class_exists both case sensitive

Tags: php

For some reason file_exists and class_exists are both case sensitive if I place my website on a server (hosted by TransIp), but if I upload them to xampp those methods are case insensitive. Does anyone know why? I'm struggling for a long time and haven't found the answer yet.

Thanks for your help!

Yours faithfully,

Joost

Comment: Windows filesystem isn't case sensitive, Linux is! And that will effect `file_exists()`... good reason to ensure that you are always consistent

Comment: `class_exists` also depends on your autoloader. (There are few that take the properties of the filesystem and PHPs identifier structs into account.)

Comment: probably because they're on a \*NIX system and you're on Windows. Edit: Oh, I see @MarkBaker already wrote what I basically wrote, my bad. Sorry Mark.

Answer (score 1):

`file_exists()`'s case sensitivity depends on the filesystem:

- on Unix-like systems the filesystem is usually case sensitive
- on Windows it's usually case insensitive (NTFS)

`class_exists()` is case insensitive BUT it will invoke the [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), which might use `file_exists()` internally => making `class_exists()` seem case sensitive on some filesystems.

The solution is to always treat class names as being case sensitive to avoid potential issues.